# File 'environ.sty' not found on Ubuntu 13.04 with texlive 2013

Tags: errors, packages, texlive, ubuntu, texstudio

I found a similar answer but regarding a different distro and the solution did not work for me, so:

- on an Ubuntu 13.04
- I made yesterday (to say that it's clean & brand new) a complete network installation of texlive
- afterwards I installed texstudio
- I tried to compile a tex file using a cls that used environ.sty

-!- texstudio complain about not finding file environ.sty

BUT

- if I try from a command line everything works fine
- `tlmgr -check` all seems ok
- `tlmgr -files` gives package environ as installed
- `kpsewhich environ.sty` outputs `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty`

I am trying to convince a bunch of people around me to get rid of M$ stuff but I'm quite a newbie too in the world of the penguin, so please help me :)

Comment: Did you install another version TeX Live from Ubuntu software source? If two versions of TeX distribution are on the same computer, check which wersion is used by TeXstudio.

Comment: Ensure the paths in TeXStudio don't point to `/usr/bin/pdflatex` or similar, but to `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/<arch>/pdflatex` (where `<arch>` is the conventional name for the machine you're using).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user38852".

Comment: If you do this again on a fresh Ubuntu install, you might be interested in [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu), which automates everything and makes it so Ubuntu doesn't install other texlive packages after installing TeX Live 2013 manually.

Comment: Are there any news here? How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I decided to walk another way:  www.sharelatex.com. Pros: no need to install anything, every package updated, can edit from anywhere, automatic backup. Cons: You need to have network access

Comment: vtc as unclear according to the above comments. No need in finding/posting an answer for a year old Q. Imho